# Multi-tier Application Design

Tags: c#, separation-of-concerns, n-tier-architecture

Before everyone throws stones at me, I have searched Google / MSDN / StackOver flow for related questions and answers but none of them suited my needs.

I'm working on a rather large application in C# - Windows Forms that is currently divided into the following:

1. Data-Layer
2. Domain-Layer
3. UI-Layer

Basically in my current situation the roles of this layers are the following

1. The Data-Layer's responsability is to communicate with the data-store, basically CRUD operations.
2. The Domain-Layer's responsability is to hold the model of our objects, create the objects, apply business-rules etc.
3. The UI-Layer, well, basically this is what the user sees and interacts with.

My problem is the following:

From the UI Layer the user has access to fields like: Name, Project Name, Project Number which basically are TextBoxes, Calendars etc - all of them are UI Components.

After the input of the user I call a method named: `AddExplorerNode(string name, string projectName, int projectNumber)` which resides in the Domain-Layer. This method is responsible based on the passed parameters to create an ***ExplorerNode Object*** ( a "special" TreeNode ) which requires the passed parameters to actually be valid.

After the object has been created, sanitized, validated etc - the same method mentioned above passes the created object to the Data-Layer which pushes it to a Cache-Repository and then to persists it to the data-store if everything went OK in the Cache.

So until now, basically everything is separated UI -> Domain -> DataLayer.

My question is, could I replace the signature of the Domain method from

`AddExplorerNode(string name, string projectName, int projectNumber)` to `AddExplorerNode(TreeNode node)` and based on the TreeNode object and its properties, construct the actual object I need ? I'm asking this because, if the Domain-Layers knows about the UI ( in this case the TreeNode UI Component ) basically we break the separation.

For example, if next year we swap **WindowsForms** to a **Console Application**, then the project is broken due to the fact that a **Console Application** will not have a TreeNode UI Component.

In this case, is it better to have a domain method which takes for example 5-10 parameters ( int's, strings, etc ) and based on those parameters to create my object or to replaces the parameters with a TreeNode UI Component which ?

Thank you in advance.

@EDIT:

I am asking this question, because a colleague of mine reviewed my code and started to refactor it. By refactoring he was exposing the actual TreeNode UI Component to the Domain-Layer. My approach was AddExplorerNode(string name, string projectName, int projectNumber) etc.

Comment: I think that if ExplorerNode is a _special_ (derived class?) TreeNode then you already failed to separate domains. Your UI layer pervades your domain and your data layer. If it's a separate object unrelated to WinForms TreeNode then this doesn't apply and it's good (but you're still coupling Domain with Data). Do not add a TreeNode because it will...couple them, you already thought about it. If you need an abstraction (to avoid functions with more than 2/3 parameters) then introduce another class. Would you like to call it **ViewModel**?

Comment: ExplorerNode is not a derived class, it's a silly named I used. Literally it is a mapped table that will hold information about a TreeNode which the user creates in the UI, based on the TreeNode the user created in the UI, I store specific properties in the database, for example: Name, Text, DateOfCreation etc.

Comment: If treenode is a windows forms component, I wouldn't expose that in the domain layer; I'd recommend creating an object representing the API you want, and then  convert that to tree nodes in the windows forms project when loading and convert back to the domain object when attempting to save it or whatever you are doing to add it.

Comment: @Brian Mains - you are right. Basically I have a object that "mimics" the TreeNode called MockNode. This MockNode holds properties such as: Text, Name, Id, etc. This MockNode object is used in the UI Layer to hold the properties of an actual TreeNode UI Component. After the TreeNode UI Component has been created, then I assign those properties to the MockNode class. Based on the MockNode properties, I create my actual object, which after validations and so on, gets passed to the DataLayer which persists it.

Comment: Keep anything UI specific to that layer. So, no, don't pass a UI specific TreeNode. Simply pass the data model that is required to create the object in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own class that acts in a similar way to TreeNode without actually being a TreeNode.

```
class TreeNodeModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int ProjectNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write a method in the UI to map (copy) TreeNodeModel to an actual TreeNode.

Comment: That is what exactly I have right now. A class, that "mimics" the actual TreeNode UI Component :-).

Comment: @darksleep In that case, you're doing it correctly at the moment. Your data model layer should reflect data only and you can translate how that is represented in the UI layer and it's up to the UI layer to do that, be it Forms, Console, web, etc :)